# Are the tenses in these sentences correct?

Tags: past-perfect, progressive-aspect

> Two years ago I ate ice-cream every day. I was doing this/had been doing this for six months. That's why I was weighing much more during that time.

Are the tenses used here correct? If yes/no, why? :D Thank you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally make some changes in your statement, firstly:

> Two years ago I **would eat** ice-cream every day

Since you added an adverbial phrase of time (*every day*), "**would**", which can also be used to state something that used to happen quite often in the past, sounds better.

> I had been doing this for six months

Is correct since the action of eating ice cream (which is represented by *this*) occurred first than the count.

Comment: Could I also say something like "Two years ago, I had been eating ice-cream for six months?"

Comment: I wouldn't say that it sounds correct. You stated two adverbial phrases of time, but stating two different occasions: Two years ago (a specific period of time) + for six months (an ongoing period of time), so it kinda doesn't make sense at all. the whole sentence's meaning probably doesn't imply what you may have intended to say; it implies that the act of *eating ice-cream for six months* occurred before *two years ago* because the past perfect implies an action that happened before another past action stated in the same sentence.

Comment: What I'm mainly trying to convey is that when you use such an adverbial phrase as "two years ago", the hearer or reader expects to hear/read an action which occurred in a specific period of time, in that case: *two years ago*. 
On the other hand, when you write/say *"for"*, the hearer/reader expects to hear/read something that was ongoing for a certain period of time, for example:

*I had worked as a chief for two years when I was hired by that company*
Working as a chief was an ongoing action for two years

This might work: 
*Two years ago, I worked as a chief for two years*